# Activity regularizer in Keras: before or after activation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Suppose I have:

```
output = Dense(units=12, activation='sigmoid', activity_regularizer=L1(1e-2))(input)
```

[Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/) says activity regularizer "apply a penalty on the layer's output", but it does not specify whether "output" means the output of the dense operation only, or that of the entire layer including activation.

For my problem I need the activity regularizer to apply after activation. In case Keras implements it the other way around, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras applies the activity regularization after the entire layer including activation.

If you scroll to the end of the [Dense layer `call` method](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e6784e4302c7b8cd116b74a784f4b78d60e83c26/keras/layers/core/dense.py#L179) you will see that, if defined, the activation is applied on the output before returning it.

The activity regularization is applied after this `call` function in the `Layer` base class. [See here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e6784e4302c7b8cd116b74a784f4b78d60e83c26/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L1132+L1135)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by thmslmr: the activity regularizer is applied on the output of the layer, therefore **after** the activation function is applied.

If you want to apply regularization **before** the softmax activation, you can move the activation function into a separate layer :

```
model.add(layers.Dense(units=12, activity_regularizer=L1(1e-2) )
model.add(layers.Activation('softmax'))
```